# dropdownlist values and text need trimmed

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist which is being populated by a sqldatasource and when I look at the HTML created afterwards there's a lot of spaces in the value and text. This must because the length of the fields in the database is 50.

e.g.

The HTML is like this

```
        <select name="DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DropDownList1\',\'\')', 0)" id="DropDownList1" style="height:23px;width:148px;">
    <option value="IT  Dev                                           ">IT  Dev                                           </option>
    <option value="Marketing                                         ">Marketing                                         </option>
    <option value="HR                                                ">HR                                                </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Finance                                           ">Finance                                           </option>
    <option value="Corporate                                         ">Corporate                                         </option>
    <option value="IT Support                                        ">IT Support                                        </option>

</select>
```

The controls source is:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
            DataValueField="dept_name" Height="23px" Width="148px">
            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:scConnString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT dept_name FROM depts"></asp:SqlDataSource
```

Can I trim the values in my sql, or the items in the dropdownlist after it has been populated?

Any ideas?

Comment: dept_name is varchar(50) or char(50)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't trim fixed length data. It'll always be padded back out to 50.

So CAST *then* trim

```
SELECT RTRIM(CAST(dept_name AS varchar(50))) AS dept_name FROM depts

--other options, after comment
SELECT RTRIM(CAST(dept_name AS varchar(50))) dept_name FROM depts
SELECT dept_name = RTRIM(CAST(dept_name AS varchar(50))) FROM depts
```

Or fix it in the client code

Comment: Drop the AS?  Or put it before dept_name?

Comment: @Narveson: my mistake sorry. I'd use AS (my 1st option) normally

Comment: tried the first and second options and got them to work..but only after removing the 'AS' after dept_name? But yeah it works nice one. Thanks;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type To VarChar or nVarChar to allow varible length of data.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your data is extracted, you may be able to trim on either end. For the second option (after population), you can use the OnDataBound event and iterate through the items to trim them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trimming in your SQL:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:scConnString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(dept_name)) FROM depts"></asp:SqlDataSource
```

Comment: You can't trim fixed length data **and** you'd need an alias

Answer (score 0):

trim spaces from sql:

```
SELECT ltrim(rtrim(dept_name)) FROM depts
```

Comment: You can't trim fixed length data **and** you'd need an alias